# Azure Private DNS Zone Link to VNets

Tags: azure, dns, azure-private-link

We have a hub and spoke topology. In the Hub we deployed a custom DNS VM.
We're using Private Endpoints and created Private DNS Zones in the Hub VNet. We created forwarding rules accordingly. The Private DNS Zones are linked with the Hub VNet.

We also have Spoke VNets that are peered with the Hub VNet. Do we also need a link from the Private DNS Zone to the Spoke VNets?

Note: The Private Endpoints reside in the Spoke VNet.

The Azure documentation is not very clear on this certain topic.
At one place we read the following: `Link the private DNS zone with all virtual networks that need to resolve your Private Endpoint DNS name.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/networking/private-link-hub-spoke-network

But at another place this is not mentioned.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#virtual-network-and-on-premises-workloads-using-a-dns-forwarder

Answer (score 1):

I have created hub and spoke vnet and peered like below:

[image]

[image]

> We also have Spoke VNets that are peered with the Hub VNet. Do we also need a link from the Private DNS Zone to the Spoke VNets?

Yes, if you want to resolve the Private Endpoint DNS name from the Spoke VNets, you need to link the Private DNS Zone with the Spoke VNets as well. Spoke VNets are peered with the Hub VNet, but they are not automatically linked with the Private DNS Zone

In private DNS zone link spoke vnet like below make sure to enable auto registration like below:

[image]
.
[image]

In the second [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#virtual-network-workloads-without-custom-dns-server) you are referring to also its stating the same.

Peered virtual networks associated to the same private endpoint. Add new virtual network links to the private DNS zone for all peered virtual networks.

> If you're using a private endpoint in a hub-and-spoke model from a different subscription or even within the same subscription, link the same private DNS zones to all spokes and hub virtual networks that contain clients that need DNS resolution from the zones.

Comment: Ok thanks. However, the Important article that you have cited is from the area without using a custom DNS server. That's why I assumed that when we run our custom DNS server we do not necessarily need this VNet link.

Comment: Can you explain which advantage has the autoregistration feature? We are referring to a API Management Private DNS Zone.

Comment: Check the MsDoc in detail https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-autoregistration

Comment: @Imran Thanks for your explanations. However, you didn't add any new facts. I already know the docs. I assumed you have some background knowledge as well.

Comment: According to this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-privatednszone), DNS resolution against a private DNS zone works only from virtual networks that are linked to it. So, spoke Vnet should also be linked to the private DNS zone even when using custom DNS.

Comment: There is a miss in a Microsoft doc diagram and this issue has been reported to Microsoft and it will be updated soon.